# How to replace first few characters in java?

Tags: java, string, jasper-reports

I have a situation where i have to replace first 4 characters of a string to 'x'.

The original data is '12345678'. I want to replace to 'xxxx5678'.

I am actually using Jasper Reports and this is my field:

```
$F{obj.contact_id.hisher_member_id}
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with substring?

Comment: `String output = "xxxx" + input.substring(4);`

Comment: Thanks a Lot Bethany.

There is nothing wrong with substring yassin, the issue is  am only not used to java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Community wiki from [Yassin Hajaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5050667/yassin-hajaj) suggestion and [Bethany Louise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494452/bethany-louise) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974812/how-to-replace-first-few-characters-in-java/36977562#comment61505093_36974812)*

In Java, using [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-), a solution is:

```
String output = "xxxx" + input.substring(4);
```

That in Jasper Reports `<textFieldExpression/>` is

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["xxxx" + $F{obj.contact_id.hisher_member_id}.substring(4)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Note: the field `$F{obj.contact_id.hisher_member_id}` class should be `java.lang.String`.